# Images and videos does not show in page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, server.xml

I have created a dynamic page and  trying to show images in videos in this page. 
I stored images and videos path in database .when i run the project in Eclips

1)  its fine but when i try to check in browser it does not show the images and videos in browser. in this condition i have set the path to my local folder D  have set the path

2) when i stored online photos link in path it works fine in both eclips and browser,

I am using Tomcat Server 8.25 and created Pages in JSP ,servlets,

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{contentDetails.location == 'NA'}">
     <img  src="#{request.contextPath}/#{operator}/content/#{param['c']}/#{contentDetails.cpCategory1}/#{contentDetails.title}.jpg" alt="#{contentDetails.category}" />
            </h:panelGroup>
             <h:panelGroup rendered="#{contentDetails.location != 'NA'}">
                <img src="#{contentDetails.location}" alt="#{contentDetails.category}"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: why do you put "#" in front of your EL expressions?